# How to use a custom draggable / dragging ghost image?

Tags: javascript, css, draggable

I have red and searched for an answer for many many posts, but still cannot find the one that will answer my question.

How do I change or use a custom ghost image for the `draggable` element?

I red somewhere during the `dragging` state, it generates a snapshot image of the `dragged` element, if so then how can the looks of the element can be changed?

here are some sceenshots of how the `dragged` element looks:
[image]
[image]

more examples while dragging:
[image]
[image]

The expected result should look like this:
[image]

you can clearly see something is very wrong with the `dragged` element

Instead of showing a `ghost image` exact copy with universal `0.5 opacity` of the original element

A `radial gradient` with `opacity` is applied to the `dragged` element

Also the `radial gradient` layout is based on the clicked position of the `mouse` (In image 2 the `text` is almost `invisible` because the `mouse` is clicked at the end of element)

I tested the same webpage in both `google chrome` and `microsoft edge`,

But both shows the `ghost image` in the same style (`radial gradient` with `opacity`)

I have recreated the same example code in `pure html` ('.html`),` reactjs`,` nextjs `etc and they all show the same (`radial gradient`with`opacity`)` ghost image`when the element is`dragged`

At this stage I am at a loss, and have no totally idea how to fix this

Is anyone kind enough to explain why this happened or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

From [mdn web docs - Drag operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#setting_the_drag_feedback_image):

> When a drag occurs, a translucent image is generated from the drag target

So basically the browser creates a screenshot of the dragged element which can be moved within or even outside the Browser window

> However you can use setDragImage() to specify a custom drag feedback image:

```js
function dragWithCustomImage(event) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = canvas.height = 50;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
  ctx.moveTo(0, 50);
  ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
  ctx.stroke();

  const dt = event.dataTransfer;
  dt.setData("text/plain", "Data to Drag");
  dt.setDragImage(canvas, 25, 25);
}
```

You can also configure the [Drag Effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#drag_effects)

For example you can set the Drag Effect to `move` or `copy`.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply! how do I recapture the snapshot of the dragged element? I am able to change the `background color` etc but the `opacity gradient` is still there (https://prnt.sc/C_pdV210mGca), any idea how to remove it?

Comment: it seems the issue is alot more complicated then I expected, this gradient transparency bug only affects windows user and on all windows browser: hi, does anyone knows why this Windows 10 html5 bug still exist? https://github.com/reppners/ngx-drag-drop/issues/93 but there are no solutions for this?

Comment: the ghost image only works when its below 300px width or height, if it exceeds the said dimensions the ugly gradient transparency bug will appear

Comment: yes the only way is to draw a custom canvas or to use a custom library like https://github.com/pmndrs/use-gesture for drag'n'drop

Comment: can you elaborate on the "custom canvas" alternative? use-gesture does nothing and seems unrelated to the use case of drag and drop with a ghost image

Comment: the canvas in my answer :)
use-gesture is a common dragndrop solution for react - check out the animated image at the top of their readme.. you will find various dragndrop examples

Comment: hi, are you refering to this use-gesture example? https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pmndrs/use-gesture/tree/main/demo/src/sandboxes/cards-stack

Comment: I have tried using use-gesture it works great out of the box, but it is not a `draggable` element, if `draggable="true"` is added together with `use-gesture` bind, it wont work, I am using `reactflow` chart with a `onDrop` event listener, without `draggable="true"` it still wont work